# Are there military commanders other than Khalid ibn al-Walid who have never been defeated?

Tags: military

I was reading about [Khalid ibn al-Walid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khalid_ibn_al-Walid), a commander in the Muslim's era. What is interesting about him is that he was never been defeated in any of the hundred battles that he encountered. Are there military commanders similar to him fought hundred of hard battles and wasn't defeated?

From Wikipedia:

> Khalid is said to have fought around a hundred battles, both major
>   battles and minor skirmishes as well as single duels, during his
>   military career. Having remained undefeated, he is claimed by some to
>   be one of the finest military generals in history.

It's a side question, but how did he accomplish to win all of these battles without being defeated? In the article it is explained that he was smart and brave, but Napoleon was also considered a smart general with new tactics, yet he was defeated in his battles.

Comment: The difficulty in comparing different commanders from different eras is that they fought different opponents in different circumstances. You might be a brilliant commander but if your opponents are too and they happen to have stronger armies, you might never get to show it. If you are lucky, and your enemies are less talented and their armies weaker, then you get to shine.

Comment: Julius Caesar comes close, with only Gergovia being a questionable victory: although Caesar suffered heavy casualties and abandoned the field of battle (a tactical defeat) the losses inflicted on the Gauls forced them in turn to relocate to Alesia, where Vercengetorix was forced to surrender some weeks later.

Comment: Another possibility is Louis-Nicolas Davout: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Nicolas_Davout. Perhaps also George S. Patton

Comment: I know one battle he was defeated: [battle of Mu tah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Mu%27tah). Although he was not the original commander in chief and only became so due to the death of his superiors. still counts as a defeat though. Furthermore there are defeats where he was not the leader [Battle of the Trench] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Trench)

Comment: @SteveBird I added it as a side question due to different era , but its enemies wasen't easy , and he fought different armies with hard circumstances.

Comment: @User999999 yes  I did read that in the wiki battle of Mu tah , but they didnt consider it as a defeat.

Comment: @moudiz: It clearly states in records: the Muslims were routed after three of their leaders were killed.  They were forced to retreat back to medina ( = defeat).  Maybe they didn't see as a defeat (power of perception). But it is seen by most  as a defeat. However your statement would be correct if you change "Having remained undefeated" to "Having remained undefeated in campaigns".

Comment: @User999999 It was a tactical Roman victory however I believe strategic defeat as they failed to destroy the meagre Force under command of Khalid and after taking command Khalid managed to retreat with his Army which is splendid result when you consider Khalid was outnumbered severely. Had Romans destroyed the Arab force there, Muslims would have been more reluctant to invade them later. Also there could be a chance that Pagan arabs would have destroyed Muslims after destruction of Muslim army in Byzantine lands

Comment: @moudiz It was nevertheless a defeat. Khalid was chosen commander at the end and his command was to salvage whatever he could of his battered forces which was a wise decision. This force was the best of what Muslims could muster at the time

Comment: @SteveBird Well as for Khalid's case, his greatest achievements and almost all of career as a general was against the Byzantine and Persian Empires whose forces were by all accounts stronger than Khalid's. (Though I am more cynical about Persian leadership, they were just waiting for a push to destroy them).

Comment: @User999999 Mu'tah was a strategic victory of Khalid (based on the number of death), or at least a draw because both armies retreated.

Comment: There are several commanders that never were defeated only because they fought one or two battles. Maybe you should define a threshold in order to get a refined answer.

Comment: I defined it in my sentence 'fought hundred of hard battles and wasn't defeated`

Comment: There are many military commanders who never fought a battle. Do those count as commanders who were never defeated? Or all the commanders who only ever fought one minor encounter and won? Do you count only generals commanding armies or also platoon leaders commanding a small recon patrol?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Several other examples would be:

- **[Thutmose III (1481-1426 BC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thutmose_III)** Arguably one of the greatest Pharaohs. Changed a kingdom into an empire.
- **[Alexander the Great (356-323 BC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_the_Great)**: Brought, amongst others, Persia to its knees
- **[Ashoka the Great (304-232 BC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashoka)**: The Maurian King who spread buddism to the Indian subcontinent
- **[Scipio Africanus the Elder (236-183 BC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scipio_Africanus)** One of the most important generals against Carthage. Led the Romans at Zama. He was never defeated in the field.
- **[Tariq ibn Ziyad (670-720)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tariq_ibn_Ziyad)**: Leader at the battle of Gaudalete. Led several campaigns into Hispania without suffering a single defeat.
- **[Timur the lenk aka Tamerlane (1330-1405)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timur)**: Founder of the Timurid Empire. Supposedly never got defeated in the field.
- **[Yi Sun Sin (1545-1598)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yi_Sun-sin)** Korean Admiral during the [Imjin War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_invasions_of_Korea_(1592%E2%80%9398)#Names). Never lost a battle at sea.
- **[Alexander Suvorov (1730-1800)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Suvorov)**: One of the great Russian generals. He led campaigns against the Poland, Ottoman Empire & the French. Is supposed to be undefeated in the field.
- **[Paul von Lettow Vorbeck(1870-1964)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_von_Lettow-Vorbeck)**: Led the Germans during WW1 in German East Africa. He never lost on the battlefield.
- **[Jan Žižka z Trocnova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_%C5%BDi%C5%BEka)**: The Hussite general who according to reading never lost a single battle. Defeated four (Anti-Hussite) crusader armies. A 5th army just ran away when seeing the Hussite Army
- **[John Churchill, 1st Duke of Marlborough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Churchill,_1st_Duke_of_Marlborough)**: Led the British in the Nine Year wars & the War of the Spanish Succession. Was never defeated in the field.
- **[Arthur Wellesley, 1st Duke of Wellington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Wellesley,_1st_Duke_of_Wellington)**: Fought in India, Flanders & Hispania (against the troops of Napoleon). Has only one "major" defeat (although it was more like a skirmish) at Burgos.

Some further correct examples offered by [NSNoob](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/15625/nsnoob)

- **[Fyodor Fyodorovich Ushakov (1766–1812)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fyodor_Ushakov)**: Russian Admiral who served in the Black Sea. Fought the Turks & the French on 43 recorded occasions without losing a single engagement or ship
- **[Bai Qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bai_Qi)**: General of the Qin Dynasty (during the Warring states period). No records were found of him losing a battle.

Some further correct examples offered by [Brasidas](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/8103/brasidas)

- **[Bajirao I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bajirao_I)**: He was important to the rise of the Maratha Empire. Although he did not always lead the armies during the campaigns, he was never defeated in the field.

I found this interesting list. But I wasn't able to completely check it yet:
[Supposed undefeated military leaders](http://wikibin.org/articles/list-of-undefeated-military-commanders.html)

Comment: Add Jan Zizka, Duke of Marlborough and Wellington, and you have an answer there.

Comment: @Brasidas I know i was forgetten some genius Generals.

Comment: You might also want to add Chinese General [Bai Qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bai_Qi) and Russian admiral [Fyodor Ushakov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fyodor_Ushakov) to the list.

Comment: I suspect some of our Indian readers would disagree with putting Alexander on your list.

Comment: @TED : I persume you mean his campaign across the Indus-River which he had to forsake due to the revolting army ( @ Hyphasis river)?

Comment: Ooops, wikipedia has listed some defeats for Wellington: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_record_of_Arthur_Wellesley,_1st_Duke_of_Wellington

Comment: @Brasidas some of the lost battles shown are in fact "victory in the field for the British" but "defeat in the strategic sense" as they were successful delay actions by the French (hence the "French Victory"). Yet I did see 2 (lost) battles that i'll investigate further. +1

Comment: @User999999 what do you mean: Jan Žižka van Trocnov: The Hussiete general who according to me never lost a battle

Comment: @Ludi: I meant "according to the records I found." I'll rephrase the sentence

Comment: [Demetrius I of Bactria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demetrius_I_of_Bactria) "was never defeated in battle and was posthumously qualified as **the Invincible**". His conquests include parts of modern Afghanistan and Pakistan

Comment: [Bajirao I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bajirao_I) "never lost a battle. According to the British Army officer Bernard Montgomery, Bajirao was 'possibly the finest cavalry general ever produced by India'".

Comment: @Brasidas added Bajirao I. Can't add Demetrius I of Bactria yet. Though he is claimed to be invincible, I can't find any reliable (& complete) records of his campaigns and battles.

Comment: Found another one for you: [King Edward IV of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_IV_of_England). Quote from Wikipedia: "Edward was an extremely capable and daring military commander. He crushed the House of Lancaster in a series of spectacular military victories, and he was never defeated on the field of battle."

Comment: I believe both Davout and Suvarov belong on that list.

Answer (score 12):

I'm actually a little dubious of the "never defeated" claim in the first place. Not only does it seem highly unlikely, but then there's this:

> Khalid utilized his better understanding of terrain in every possible
>   way to gain strategic superiority over his enemies. During his Persian
>   campaigns, he initially never entered deep into Persian territory and
>   always kept the Arabian desert at his rear, allowing his forces to
>   retreat there **in case of a defeat**

That seems pretty unnecessary (and certainly not worth noting as a smart tactic) if he truly never suffered a rebuff. The more likely explanation is that he was using this tactic to stage ambushes, and then retreating once (if) the superior force organized itself.

Now in military terminology of course both sides like to claim victory if they can at all make a case for it. So what we have taken to doing in order to be somewhat objective about it is saying that the side that retains the field at the end of the engagement was the victor. Admittedly this means often the "victor" has suffered some manner of strategic setback, but that's how we term it.

In either case, any time a commander uses the tactic quoted above to effect a retreat, it is technically considered a "defeat" in the engagement. That doesn't mean its a dumb thing to do, but you can't say he's "undefeated".

I bring this up because history is full of commanders who were very successful overall, but in part because they knew when to retreat, and could do it in good order. In fact, its pretty much required. The counter-example is Pyrrhus, who is said to have "won" pretty much [all his major battles against Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrhic_War) (no retreats), yet lost his war.

Comment: I'd suggest that keeping a contingency plan is mark of a smart leader. Defeats can happen. A smart leader keeps his escape route open and his plan ready. A silly leader puts his soldiers in chains to avoid a rout. It's not like he would have known that every battle he would fight would turn out to be a clear or strategic victory for him.

Comment: Ah just read the last lines "but in part because they knew when to retreat, and could do it in good order".

Answer (score 4):

According to Winston Churchill, "A History of the English Speaking People," pp. 90-91:

"For ten years, [the Duke of Marlborough led the armies of the Grand Alliance, [England, the Netherlands, several German states] and during all that period he never fought a battle he did not win or besieged a town he did not take. Nothing like this exists in the annals of war."

He won major battles against the French during Queen Anne's War from 1702-1711 at Blenheim, Ramilles, Oudenarde, and Malplaquet, although some consider the last a "Pyrrhic" victory.

Answer (score 1):

I was told that the Malplaquet battle was a French victory since the British lost too many men to continue. Villars even said "Si Dieu nous fait la grâce de perdre encore une pareille bataille, Votre Majesté peut compter que ses ennemis sont détruits" (Which means that if the French would lose another fight like this, their foes would be destroyed).
Maurice de Saxe was also never defeated.

[Source: Wikipedia article on [Bataille de Malplaquet in French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bataille_de_Malplaquet)]

Comment: It would be nicer if you could add some reference or research that can support your answer.

Comment: Well I used the french wikipedia page and my notes from military history class.

Comment: There could be users who can read French and you can always link the page. Also, it would be nicer if you could translate the essential parts (two or three sentences) to English so that a user like myself can read it. Thanks.

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bataille_de_Malplaquet

Comment: For the translation my english is not good enough to do it precisely ... It will not be better than what I already wrote.

Comment: I see. I suggested the edit for a review. Please take a look and try to follow this format in the future. Good luck.

Comment: The [English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Malplaquet) calls it a "Pyrrhic victory", as the British held the field, but suffered so many casualties they were unable to pursue when the French retreated.  The French Wikipedia calls it a French tactical defeat but a strategic victory: the French retreated from the field, but were able to keep the British from attaining their large-scale goals.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet mentioned: [Muqali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muqali), one of Genghis Khan's finest commanders.

> During the invasion of Jin China, Muqali acted as Genghis Khan's second-in-command, and was promoted to Viceroy of China, and was entrusted with a great degree of autonomy once Genghis Khan departed to conquer Central Asia. Unlike many Mongol leaders who were willing to massacre to gain any advantage, Muqali usually attempted to convert foes into friends by more conciliatory means, and change the Mongol image in China. By the time of Ogedei's reign (1229-1241), he was viewed as the best of the extraordinarily talented pool of Mongol generals. Given his undefeated record despite very limited resources, he is likely one of the greatest military commanders in history.

There is also [Nader Shah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nader_Shah), the last great Asiatic conqueror. Many have called him a military genius comparable to Alexander the Great & Napoleon. He won many victories in spite of being heavily outnumbered. I am not aware of him ever having lost a battle (although he did fight numerous campaigns and I did not look through all of them).

Finally Han general [Han Xin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_Xin) is apparently undefeated as well.

> Han Xin is best remembered as a brilliant military leader for the strategies and tactics he employed in warfare, some of which became the origins of certain Chinese idioms, he was undefeated in battle and for his accomplishments he was considered the "God of War".